# Making a table for Maxwell's Equations

Tags: tables

I would like to write this in LaTeX. I tried using the `array` environment but  I think I should use the `tabular` environment. The problem is the text is outside the margins of the paper. How can I fix this?

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{units}
\begin{document}
\textbf{\begin{center}
{\Large MAXWELL’S EQUATIONS}
\end{center}}

Maxwell’s equations summarize electromagnetism and form its foundation,
including optics.
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}[l]{l l l}
Gauss’ law for electricity & $\oint \overrightarrow{E}\cdot d\overrightarrow{\! A}=\frac{q_\textrm{enc}}{\varepsilon_0}$ & Relates net electric flux to net enclosed electric charge\\
Gauss’ law for magnetism & $\oint \overrightarrow{B}\cdot d\overrightarrow{\! A}=0$ & Relates net magnetic flux to net enclosed magnetic charge\\
Faraday’s law & $\oint \overrightarrow{E}\cdot d\overrightarrow{\! s}=\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}$ & Relates induced electric field to changing magnetic flux\\
Ampere – Maxwell law & $\oint \overrightarrow{B}\cdot d\overrightarrow{\! s}=\mu_0\varepsilon_0\frac{d\Phi_E}{dt}+\mu_0i_\textrm{enc}$ & Relates induced magnetic field to changing electric flux 
and to current\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I also would like to know how to make the equations to be in display mode. When I entered the `$$` sign, there's an error message. I am relatively new to LaTeX.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the `array` environment? To change the length of a specific column look at [column option `p`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375635/defining-column-width-using-pwidth-in-tabular-environment), for auto line-break look at [tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166743/automatic-line-break-in-tabular) but I would be surprised it plays well with math. You can also designate [entire columns as math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112576/math-mode-in-tabular-without-having-to-use-everywhere).

Comment: One way could be to use the `\usepackage{geometry}` package and redefine the borders of your document `\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,right=3cm,left=2.5cm}`. Another way could be to make a linebreak in the description of the equations (look e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40561/table-with-multiple-lines-in-some-cells)).

Comment: It's hard to tell what your problem was with display mode.  `$$` isn't allowed in a tabular nor array, but would be fine on its own (although `\[` and `\]` are preferred over `$$`).  You could also look into the `align` environment.

Comment: You should really make the differential `d`s upright, the italic letter `d` is already taken for the dipole moment.

Comment: It's an insult to Mr Lenz to write Faraday's law without the minus sign. Many things depend on that!!! ;)

Answer (score 12):

It's difficult to fit such big objects in a table without making line breaks.

Here's my suggestion: the laws' names on a line by themselves, in italic type; then the mathematical law and its description.

Some spacing between rows will help in dividing the four parts. With `tabularx` the second column takes all the space left free by the first column. With `>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}` the first column is typeset flush left, in display style like when in displays (don't use `$$` in general, but the proper environments).

Finally, I added a command for the differential; since it *may* happen that you're required to make the “d” upright, it's better having it in the code as a command, so you can just change the definition.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,tabularx}
\usepackage{esvect}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}\bfseries\Large
MAXWELL’S EQUATIONS
\end{center}

Maxwell’s equations summarize electromagnetism and form its foundation,
including optics.
\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{$\displaystyle}l<{$} X @{}}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\itshape Gauss’ law for electricity} \\
\addlinespace[2pt]
  \oint \vec{E}\cdot \diff\vec{A}=
    \frac{q_{\mathrm{enc}}}{\varepsilon_0} &
  Relates net electric flux to net enclosed electric charge\\

\addlinespace

\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\itshape Gauss’ law for magnetism} \\
\addlinespace[2pt]
  \oint \vec{B}\cdot \diff\vec{A}=0 &
  Relates net magnetic flux to net enclosed magnetic charge\\

\addlinespace

\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\itshape Faraday’s law} \\
\addlinespace[2pt]
  \oint \vec{E}\cdot \diff\vec{s}=
    -\frac{\diff\Phi_B}{\diff t} &
  Relates induced electric field to changing magnetic flux\\

\addlinespace

\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\itshape Ampère--Maxwell law} \\
\addlinespace[2pt]
  \oint \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{s}=
    \mu_0\varepsilon_0\frac{\diff\Phi_E}{\diff t}+\mu_0i_{\mathrm{enc}} &
   Relates induced magnetic field to changing electric flux and to current\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Instead of `\overrightarrow` that adds a too big arrow, it's better to use `\vec` or make the vector's symbols bold.

Note also that `_\textrm{enc}` and similar only works by chance. It should better be `_{\mathrm{enc}}`.

A stylistic remark: you want to center something which is large in size and boldface, not to boldface something that's centered.

[image]

If you also do `\usepackage{bm}` and add

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}
```

the output would become

[image]

Comment: +1 for also replacing `\overrightarrow` with `\vec`. :-)

Comment: @Mico I don't like `\vec` either, to tell you the truth, so I added a “more modern” notation.

Comment: There's a minus sign missing in Faraday's law, one small step to perfection! ;)

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Thanks; it's been a few years since when I studied Maxwell's laws and I trusted in the OP's fresher memories. ;-)

Comment: @egreg `\vv` from the `esvect` package provides nicer arrows than `\vec` and `\overrightarrow`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Thanks for the suggestion. However, I like them even less than the standard `\vec`. Personal opinion, of course.

Comment: @egreg For how they look, personal opinion, indeed :) But IMO `esvect` handles better "long" vectors (compare `\vec{AB}` and `\vv{AB}`).

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution that uses a `tabularx` environment and permits line breaks in columns 1 and 3. Column 2 is processed automatically in displaystyle math mode.

[image]

Observe also that I replaced all instances of the overly large `\overrightarrow` arrows with `\vec` and removed the uppercasing from the title line. I followed @Schrödinger'scat suggestion to typeset the "differential operator" d's using upright lettering -- by the way, the source of the `\diff` macro appears to be in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84308/5001) to the query [What is the difference [between] `\mathop`, `\operatorname` and `\DeclareMathOperator`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84302/5001). Finally (?), I fixed the sign error that was present in the OP's formulation of the third equation after @campa brought it to my attention.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}} % automatic displaystyle math mode
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Ampere--Maxwell}        % determine width of 1st column
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}} % upright differential operator
   %% Source for "\diff" macro: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84308/5001

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\Large\bfseries Maxwell's Equations
\end{center}
Maxwell's equations summarize electromagnetism and form its foundation, including optics.

\bigskip\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} K{\mylen} M L @{}}
Gauss' law for electricity & 
  \oint \vec{E}\cdot \diff\vec{A}=\frac{q_{\mathrm{enc}}}{\varepsilon_0} & 
  Relates net electric flux to net enclosed electric charge\\
Gauss' law for magnetism & 
  \oint \vec{B}\cdot \diff\vec{A}=0 & 
  Relates net magnetic flux to net enclosed magnetic charge\\
Faraday's law & 
  \oint \vec{E}\cdot \diff\vec{s}=-\frac{\diff\Phi_B}{\diff t} & 
  Relates induced electric field to changing magnetic flux\\
Ampere--Maxwell law & 
  \oint \vec{B}\cdot \diff\vec{s}=\mu_0\varepsilon_0\frac{\diff\Phi_E}{\diff t}+\mu_0i_{\mathrm{enc}} & 
  Relates induced magnetic field to changing electric flux and to current
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought of this, but eventually rejected it. Anyway, hyphenation in the first column is not nice: using `\raggedright` in it would be better.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for this suggestion. I've modified my answer to use `\raggedright` rather than `\RaggedRight` in the first column.

Comment: Please consider making the differentials upright, so that physicists can upvote your otherwise nice answer. In the context of the Maxwell equations this is particularly important to distinguish it from a dipole moment, say.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat - Thanks for this suggestion, which I was happy to implement. I found 8 instances of the differential-d -- did I miss any?

Comment: Let's count: +1 for the nice table, +1 for the upright differential, -1 for the wrong sign (boy, I would so fail you in an exam... `;-)`), and I don't like SI units but I'll live. +1 in total `:-)`

Comment: @campa -- Fixed. Darn, the secret is out that I'm not a physicist. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Also with tabularx, but with more appropriate margins, thanks to `geometry` , and redefining the `X` column type, to have the descriptions vertically centred, in a slightly smaller font (with a normalsize of 11pt, the descriptions are in 10pt):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{units}
\begin{document}
\textbf{\begin{center}
{\Large MAXWELL’S EQUATIONS}
\end{center}}

Maxwell’s equations summarize electromagnetism and form its foundation,
including optics.
\bigskip

\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[l]{@{}l >{$\displaystyle}l<{$}X@{}}
Gauss’ law for electricity & \oint \overrightarrow{E}\cdot d\overrightarrow{\! A}=\frac{q_\textrm{enc}}{\varepsilon_0}& Relates net electric flux to net enclosed electric charge\\[2ex]
Gauss’ law for magnetism & \oint \overrightarrow{B}\cdot d\overrightarrow{\! A}=0 & Relates net magnetic flux to net enclosed magnetic charge\\[2ex]
Faraday’s law & \oint \overrightarrow{E}\cdot d\overrightarrow{\! s}=\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt} & Relates induced electric field to changing magnetic flux\\[2ex]
Ampère–Maxwell law & \oint \overrightarrow{B}\cdot d\overrightarrow{\! s}=\mu_0\varepsilon_0\frac{d\Phi_E}{dt}+\mu_0i_\textrm{enc} & Relates induced magnetic field to changing electric flux
and to current
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You changed the definition of `\tabularxcolumn` in two ways from its default: (a) switch from `p` to `m` and (b) switch from `\normalsize` to `\small`. Is the second part intentional? If so, you should probably make it explicit in your write-up.

Comment: @Mico: yes, I retained  \small from the example in tabularx documentation, as the layout was better, and more generally I prefer descriptions/explanations/ comments in a slightly smaller font: their semantic status is not the same as the first two columns.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution only for fun!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,palatino}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|m{0.3\linewidth}|>{\centering$\displaystyle}m{0.3\linewidth}<{$}|m{0.4\linewidth}|}\hline
Gauss' law      
    &   \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B} = 0 
    & Relates net electric flux to net enclosed electric charge.\\\hline
Gauss' law      
    &   \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{D} = \rho_{\text{enc}} 
    & Relates net magnetic flux to net enclosed magnetic charge.\\\hline
Faraday's law 
    &   \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E} = - \frac{\partial B}{\partial\, t}
    & Relates induced electric field to changing magnetic flux. \\\hline
Ampere-Maxwell law 
    &   \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{H} = \vec{J} + \frac{\partial \vec{D}}{\partial\, t}
    & Relates induced magnetic field to changing electric flux and to current. \\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The description for the first and second rows must be swapped.

Comment: The frame makes the contents stood out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\displaystyle` at the beginning of each math mode to force display style math formatting.